# Insert custom build code / invoke java programm with Maven during build

Tags: java, maven

I am having a project where there is code being generated by a third-party tool (typically invoked from the command line). I would like to align this tool with our maven build setup, i.e. I would like to have it invoked, for example before `maven compile`.

Is there a way to execute an arbitrary Java program using one of the numerous maven plugins? Where would I insert it in the POM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), using its `exec` goal, which lets you execute an external application.

About *when* the external application is going to be executed, you have to consider the [default Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). When you launch the `build` process, Maven executes the following (strictly ordered) phases:

1. validate
2. compile
3. test
4. package
5. integration-test
6. verify
7. install
8. deploy

You can decide at which of the steps above running the external application by configuring the `phase` element in the **Exec Maven Plugin** `executions` element:

```
<!-- Begin of POM -->
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Begin of Exec Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase> <!-- Here, for example, validate -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>...</configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Begin of Exec Maven Plugin -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
<!-- End of POM -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Use maven-exec-plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
             <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>exec-one</id>
                     <phase>verify</phase>
                     <configuration>
                         <executable>echo</executable>
                         <arguments>
                             <argument>exec one</argument>
                         </arguments>
                     </configuration>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>exec</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>                     
            </executions>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Just like any other plugin it should be specified in a "build" section of POM file